Forgejo pid file (/var/run/forgejo.pid) : not readable in Truenas Core (FreeBSD Jail)
I have been trying to get Forgejo running in a Truenas Core (FreeBSD jail) for over a week. When I manually start Forgejo as the git user it runs as expected, however attempting to get it to run with the included rc file provided by the ports package it errors out.
Forgejo Port
rc.d script
When I start forgejo manually it runs:
root@Forgejo:/home/jailuser # su git
git@Forgejo:/home/jailuser $ forgejo web -c /usr/local/etc/forgejo/conf/app.ini
2024/04/23 18:59:36 cmd/web.go:242:runWeb() [I] Starting Forgejo on PID: 4748
2024/04/23 18:59:36 cmd/web.go:111:showWebStartupMessage() [I] Forgejo version:1.21.11-1 built with GNU Make 4.4.1, go1.21.9 : bindata, pam, sqlite, sqlite_unlock_notify

However, when I attempt to start the forgejo service I get the following pid not found error:
root@Forgejo:/home/jailuser # service forgejo start
/usr/local/etc/rc.d/forgejo: DEBUG: Sourcing /etc/defaults/rc.conf
/usr/local/etc/rc.d/forgejo: DEBUG: pid file (/var/run/forgejo.pid): not readable.
/usr/local/etc/rc.d/forgejo: DEBUG: checkyesno: forgejo_enable is set to YES.
/usr/local/etc/rc.d/forgejo: DEBUG: run_rc_command: doit: forgejo_start

_
root@Forgejo:/home/jailuser # mount
Main/iocage/jails/Forgejo/root on / (zfs, local, noatime, nfsv4acls)
root@Forgejo:/home/jailuser # ll /var
total 81
drwxr-x---   2 root     wheel     2 Mar  1 18:50 account/
drwxr-xr-x   4 root     wheel     4 Mar  1 18:50 at/
drwxr-x---   4 root     audit     4 Mar  1 18:50 audit/
drwxrwx---   2 root     authpf    2 Mar  1 18:50 authpf/
drwxr-x---   2 root     wheel     8 Apr 23 03:21 backups/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root     wheel     2 Mar  1 18:50 cache/
drwxr-x---   2 root     wheel     3 Mar  1 19:06 crash/
drwxr-x---   3 root     wheel     3 Mar  1 18:50 cron/
drwxr-xr-x  14 root     wheel    17 Apr 20 21:43 db/
dr-xr-xr-x   2 root     wheel     2 Mar  1 18:50 empty/
drwxrwxr-x   2 root     games     2 Mar  1 18:50 games/
drwx------   2 root     wheel     2 Mar  1 18:50 heimdal/
drwxr-xr-x   3 root     wheel    23 Apr 23 00:00 log/
drwxrwxr-x   2 root     mail      5 Apr 20 21:01 mail/
drwxr-xr-x   2 daemon   wheel     3 Apr 20 19:28 msgs/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root     wheel     2 Mar  1 18:50 preserve/
drwxr-xr-x   6 root     wheel    18 Apr 23 18:56 run/
drwxrwxr-x   2 root     daemon    2 Mar  1 18:50 rwho/
drwxr-xr-x   9 root     wheel     9 Mar  1 18:50 spool/
drwxrwxrwt   3 root     wheel     3 Mar  1 18:50 tmp/
drwxr-xr-x   3 unbound  unbound   3 Mar  1 18:50 unbound/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root     wheel     4 Mar  1 19:24 yp/
root@Forgejo:/home/jailuser #

Manually executing the daemon command results in an exit status of 0 with no other useful information. Tried relocating the pid file to a directory with 777 permissions and still getting the same error. My only guess right now would be that forgejo is dying almost immediately before daemon is able to create the pid file? Not sure how to get stdout from forgejo to see if there are any errors (forgejo is not logging anything to its log file directory). Any ideas?
UPDATE:
Adding truss to the init script on the call to daemon yields the following:
53609: mmap(0x0,135168,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANON,-1,0x0) = 34376810496 (0x801048000)
53609: mprotect(0x801044000,4096,PROT_READ) = 0 (0x0)
53609: issetugid()              = 0 (0x0)
53609: sigfastblock(0x1,0x801047490)        = 0 (0x0)
53609: open("/etc/libmap.conf",O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC,0101130030) = 3 (0x3)
53609: fstat(3,{ mode=-rw-r--r-- ,inode=16052,size=35,blksize=4096 }) = 0 (0x0)
53609: read(3,"includedir /usr/local/etc/libmap.d\n",35) = 35 (0x23)
53609: close(3)                 = 0 (0x0)
53609: open("/usr/local/etc/libmap.d",O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC,0165) ERR#2 'No such file or directory'
53609: open("/var/run/ld-elf.so.hints",O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC,0100416054) = 3 (0x3)
53609: read(3,"Ehnt\^A\0\0\0\M^@\0\0\0w\0\0\0\0\0\0\0v\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0",128) = 128 (0x80)
53609: fstat(3,{ mode=-r--r--r-- ,inode=741826,size=247,blksize=4096 }) = 0 (0x0)
53609: pread(3,"/lib/casper:/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/lib/compat:/usr/local/lib:/usr/local/lib/compat/pkg:/usr/local/lib/perl5/5.36/mach/CORE\0",119,0x80) = 119 (0x77)
53609: close(3)                 = 0 (0x0)
53609: open("/lib/casper/libutil.so.9",O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC|O_VERIFY,00) ERR#2 'No such file or directory'
53609: open("/lib/libutil.so.9",O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC|O_VERIFY,00) = 3 (0x3)
53609: fstat(3,{ mode=-r--r--r-- ,inode=190,size=79952,blksize=80384 }) = 0 (0x0)
53609: mmap(0x0,4096,PROT_READ,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_PREFAULT_READ,3,0x0) = 34376945664 (0x801069000)
53609: mmap(0x0,98304,PROT_NONE,MAP_GUARD,-1,0x0) = 34376949760 (0x80106a000)
53609: mmap(0x80106a000,32768,PROT_READ,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_NOCORE|MAP_PREFAULT_READ,3,0x0) = 34376949760 (0x80106a000)
53609: mmap(0x801072000,49152,PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_NOCORE|MAP_PREFAULT_READ,3,0x7000) = 34376982528 (0x801072000)
53609: mmap(0x80107e000,4096,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_PREFAULT_READ,3,0x12000) = 34377031680 (0x80107e000)
53609: mmap(0x80107f000,4096,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_PREFAULT_READ,3,0x12000) = 34377035776 (0x80107f000)
53609: mmap(0x801080000,8192,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANON,-1,0x0) = 34377039872 (0x801080000)
53609: munmap(0x801069000,4096)         = 0 (0x0)
53609: close(3)                 = 0 (0x0)
53609: open("/lib/casper/libc.so.7",O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC|O_VERIFY,012320443000) ERR#2 'No such file or directory'
53609: open("/lib/libc.so.7",O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC|O_VERIFY,012320443000) = 3 (0x3)
53609: fstat(3,{ mode=-r--r--r-- ,inode=126,size=1940168,blksize=131072 }) = 0 (0x0)
53609: mmap(0x0,4096,PROT_READ,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_PREFAULT_READ,3,0x0) = 34376945664 (0x801069000)
53609: mmap(0x0,4190208,PROT_NONE,MAP_GUARD,-1,0x0) = 34377048064 (0x801082000)
53609: mmap(0x801082000,540672,PROT_READ,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_NOCORE|MAP_PREFAULT_READ,3,0x0) = 34377048064 (0x801082000)
53609: mmap(0x801106000,1343488,PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_NOCORE|MAP_PREFAULT_READ,3,0x83000) = 34377588736 (0x801106000)
53609: mmap(0x80124e000,40960,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_PREFAULT_READ,3,0x1ca000) = 34378932224 (0x80124e000)
53609: mmap(0x801258000,24576,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_PREFAULT_READ,3,0x1d3000) = 34378973184 (0x801258000)
53609: mmap(0x80125e000,2240512,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANON,-1,0x0) = 34378997760 (0x80125e000)
53609: munmap(0x801069000,4096)         = 0 (0x0)
53609: close(3)                 = 0 (0x0)
53609: mprotect(0x80124e000,36864,PROT_READ)    = 0 (0x0)
53609: mprotect(0x80124e000,36864,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE) = 0 (0x0)
53609: mprotect(0x80124e000,36864,PROT_READ)    = 0 (0x0)
53609: readlink("/etc/malloc.conf",0x7fffffffc610,1024) ERR#2 'No such file or directory'
53609: issetugid()              = 0 (0x0)
53609: mmap(0x0,2097152,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANON|MAP_ALIGNED(21),-1,0x0) = 34382807040 (0x801600000)
53609: mmap(0x0,2097152,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANON|MAP_ALIGNED(12),-1,0x0) = 34384904192 (0x801800000)
53609: mmap(0x0,4194304,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANON|MAP_ALIGNED(21),-1,0x0) = 34387001344 (0x801a00000)
53609: mprotect(0x1026000,4096,PROT_READ)   = 0 (0x0)
53609: sigaction(SIGHUP,{ SIG_IGN SA_RESTART ss_t },{ SIG_DFL 0x0 ss_t }) = 0 (0x0)
53609: sigaction(SIGTERM,{ SIG_IGN SA_RESTART ss_t },{ SIG_DFL 0x0 ss_t }) = 0 (0x0)
53609: socket(PF_LOCAL,SOCK_DGRAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC,0) = 3 (0x3)
53609: getsockopt(3,SOL_SOCKET,SO_SNDBUF,0x7fffffffd85c,0x7fffffffd858) = 0 (0x0)
53609: setsockopt(3,SOL_SOCKET,SO_SNDBUF,0x7fffffffd85c,4) = 0 (0x0)
53609: connect(3,{ AF_UNIX "/var/run/logpriv" },106) = 0 (0x0)
53609: openat(AT_FDCWD,"/var/run",O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC,00) = 4 (0x4)
53609: openat(4,"forgejo.pid",O_WRONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CREAT|O_CLOEXEC,0600) = 5 (0x5)
53609: flock(5,LOCK_EX|LOCK_NB)         = 0 (0x0)
53609: fstatat(4,"forgejo.pid",{ mode=-rw------- ,inode=742728,size=0,blksize=131072 },0x0) = 0 (0x0)
53609: fstat(5,{ mode=-rw------- ,inode=742728,size=0,blksize=131072 }) = 0 (0x0)
53609: ftruncate(5,0x0)             = 0 (0x0)
53609: fstat(5,{ mode=-rw------- ,inode=742728,size=0,blksize=131072 }) = 0 (0x0)
53609: cap_rights_limit(4,{ CAP_UNLINKAT }) = 0 (0x0)
53609: cap_rights_limit(5,{ CAP_PWRITE,CAP_FTRUNCATE,CAP_FSTAT,CAP_EVENT }) = 0 (0x0)
53609: sigaction(SIGHUP,{ SIG_IGN 0x0 ss_t },{ SIG_IGN SA_RESTART ss_t }) = 0 (0x0)
53609: fork()                   = 53610 (0xd16a)
53610: <new process>
53610: setsid()                 = 53610 (0xd16a)
53609: exit(0x0)                
53609: process exit, rval = 0
53610: sigaction(SIGHUP,{ SIG_IGN SA_RESTART ss_t },0x0) = 0 (0x0)
53610: madvise(0x0,0,MADV_PROTECT)      ERR#1 'Operation not permitted'
53610: pipe2(0x7fffffffd9c0,0)          = 0 (0x0)
53610: kqueuex()                ERR#78 'Function not implemented'
53610: SIGNAL 12 (SIGSYS) code=SI_KERNEL
53610: process killed, signal = 12

UPDATE:
TrueNAS-13.0-U6.1
jailuser@Forgejo:~ $ uname -a
FreeBSD Forgejo 13.1-RELEASE-p9 FreeBSD 13.1-RELEASE-p9 n245429-296d095698e TRUENAS amd64


First of all: if the port doesn't work out of the box, that would constitute a bug that the port maintainers would want to know about. Tell them! They also might be the most competent to help you. Now, helping yourself: Can you modify the service to start truss -o /var/log/forgejo.truss -s 1024 /usr/sbin/forgejo web" instead of just starting /usr/sbin/forgejo web? That would give you a log file in which you can look for the syscall failing to create the pidfile. The 777 directory idea is a bad one; a lot of software checks especially against that.

Added truss before the call to Forgejo, that did not yield any results (no log file). I then tried adding truss before daemon and got:
fork()
exit(0x0)
So, the error seems to be after the fork but before the exec of Forgejo. I then added the -f flag to truss and got the following:
sigaction (SIGHUP, { SIG_IGN SA_RESTART ss_t },0x0) = 0  (0x0)
madvise(0x0,0,MADV_PROTECT)      ERR#1 'Operation not permitted'
pipe2 (0x7fffffffd9c0,0)    = 0 (0x0)
kqueuex()     ERR#78 'Function not implemented'
SIGNAL 12 (SIGSYS) code=SI_KERNEL
process killed, signal = 12

Which version of Truenas CORE, exactly? (Please edit this information into the question – thank you.)

@MarcusMüller it's too soon to assume a bug in the port. We need essentials such as version information.

2024-03-07, archived:

WARNING - don't upgrade your TrueNAS CORE jails to FreeBSD 13.3 just yet | TrueNAS Community

Today, https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/forgejo-failing-to-start-as-service-pid-file-not-readable.93214/#post-653734:

FreeBSD 13.3

TrueNAS CORE 13.3 is not yet released.
TrueNAS CORE 13.3 Plans - Announcements - TrueNAS Community Forums
(I'm present there, and in other TrueNAS Community topics.)
